The reals: a topological lattice in more than the obvious way?
Define a topological lattice as a (not necessarily bounded) lattice in $\textbf{Top}$, i.e. meet and join are continuous maps $X^2 \rightarrow X$. There are two obvious topological lattice structures on $\mathbb{R}$, and they are dual to each other. Is there another?

If you have another structure with join $\vee$ and meet $\wedge$, then you can define, for each $x$, a continuous self-map of $\mathbb R$ by $y \mapsto \begin{cases} x \vee y, & x \vee y \ne x \ x \wedge y, & x \vee y = x. \end{cases}$ I wonder if one can show that this map is a homeomorphism?

@LSpice If $x \vee y = x$ then $x \wedge y = y$. Also, this map is almost never a homeomorphism, because then $x \vee y = y$ implies $y = x$ by injectivity, so the upward closure of $x$ is trivial, so $x$ is the top element and thus this map is actually the constant map.

Good point about $x \vee y = x \implies x \wedge y = y$. I'm not sure what the rest of your comment indicates; I believe the map is a homeomorphism if and only if the lattice structure is one of the obvious ones. (Maybe it's iff this map and a suitable dual are both homeomorphisms, or something like that.)

These are the only ones.
Write $x \preceq y$ if and only if $x = x \wedge y$ if and only if $y = x \vee y$, and write $\leq$ for the usual partial order on $\mathbf R$. To avoid some case separations, we will write $[a,b]$ for the union $[a,b] \cup [b,a]$ (in other words, the numbers between $a$ and $b$, regardless of whether $a \leq b$ or $a \geq b$).
Lemma. Let $a,b \in \mathbf R$ such that $a \preceq b$, and let $c \in [a,b]$. Then $a \preceq c \preceq b$.
Proof. Let $f(x) = a \vee x$, which is continuous and satisfies $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $d \in [a,b]$ such that $f(d) = c$. This means $a \vee d = c$, so in particular $a \preceq c$. The statement $c \preceq b$ follows dually. $\square$
Lemma. The partial order $\preceq$ is linear.
Proof. Let $a < b$ in $\mathbf R$, and let $c = a \vee b$ and $d = a \wedge b$. If $c \geq b$, then $a \preceq c$ implies $a \preceq b$ by the previous lemma, so $a$ and $b$ are comparable. If $c \leq a$, the lemma likewise gives $b \preceq a$. Finally, if $a \leq c \leq b$, then there are two cases: if $d \leq c$, then $d \preceq b$ and the lemma give $c \preceq b$, so $b = c$. Likewise, if $d \geq c$, then $d \preceq a$ and the lemma give $c \preceq a$, so $a = c$. In all cases, we conclude that $a$ and $b$ are comparable. $\square$
Now the proof is easy: continuity implies that the locus $\{(x,y) \in \mathbf R^2\ |\ x \preceq y\}$ is closed, as it is the equaliser of $\wedge$ and the first projection $\mathbf R^2 \to \mathbf R$. Since $\preceq$ is linear, we conclude that the locus $\{(x,y) \in \mathbf R^2\ |\ x \succ y\}$ is open, and the same goes for $\{(x,y) \in \mathbf R^2\ |\ x \prec y\}$. These partition $\mathbf R^2 \setminus \Delta$ into clopens, so one must be $\{(x,y) \in \mathbf R^2\ |\ x > y\}$ and the other $\{(x,y) \in \mathbf R^2\ |\ x < y\}$. $\square$
Remark. This proof was inspired by the following near miss: an example of a meet semilattice that does work:
\begin{align*}
\wedge \colon \mathbf R^2 &\to \mathbf R\\
(x,y) &\mapsto \begin{cases}\min(x,y), & x, y \geq 0, \\ \max(x,y), & x,y \leq 0, \\ 0, & \text{else}.\end{cases}
\end{align*}
However, it has no joins: if $x < 0 < y$, there is no $z$ with $x \preceq z \succeq y$. This is covered in (the dual of) the last case of the second lemma, as $x < x \wedge y < y$.

Very clever! I never thought to use IVT on the induced ramp function, that was the insight I was missing. Also nice semilattice find.
